# Why is it I cannot utilize paperspace GPU despite it existing in the paperspace CORE VM?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

[image]

This is an error I encounter with multiple virtual machines on paperspace. After uploading torch, torchvision and torchaudio that are compatible with the existing cuda support version as referenced here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/ I am unable to successfully detect the GPU using torch.cuda.is_available() which I require for my project. I encounter this same issue with different machines such as RTX400 and A400 in which uses 11.5 and 10.1 cuda support respectively. I am trying to get this set up:

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.1 -c conda-forge
pip install torch==1.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
pip install torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
pip install torchaudio==0.10.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```